# If tuple index out of range, start from the beginning

Tags: python, iterator, tuples

As a practice I'm writing that Cesar Cypher thingy and I have a little issue, to which I couldn't find solution.
My code looks like that:

```
def cypher(text, num):
    ''' Encypts provided message with given cyphering number'''
    
    alph = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', \
        'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0', ' ', '.', ',', '?', '!')

    coded = ''

    for char in text.upper():
        letter_i = alph.index(char)
        coded_letter = alph[letter_i + num]
        coded += coded_letter
    print(f'Your encrypted phrase is: {coded}')

def decypher(text, num):
    '''Decrypts provided message with given decyphering number'''

    alph = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', \
        'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0', ' ', '.', ',', '?', '!')
    
    decoded = ''

    for char in text.upper():
        letter_i = alph.index(char)
        decoded_letter = alph[letter_i - num]
        decoded += decoded_letter
    print(f'Your decrypted phrase is: {decoded}')
```

Now the problem is, that if I want to cypher a character that is at the far end of the tuple (e.g. "?" with code number >1) I get an error: IndexError: tuple index out of range.

I obviously know why the error comes up and I wish to solve it by iterating over the tuple again so in other words - start from the beginning.

Let's say if I go with:

```
cypher('!', 1)
```

I want to get 'A' back. Any ideas on how to loop that around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `modulo %` operator to get back at the beginning, if you go after the length of your alphabet. It works aussi for negative value (because accessing -10 is ok, but -40 is not)

Example for cypher

```
letter   index_value   num   >  index_result   %41   letter_out
!        40            1        41             0     A
!        40            2        42             1     B
```

Code

```
# cypher
coded_letter = alph[(letter_i + num) % len(alph)]

# decypher
decoded_letter = alph[(letter_i - num) % len(alph)]
```

You can now use any  delta value, it'll work

```
cypher("!ABC", 12608)  # UVWX
decypher("UVWX", 12608)  # !ABC
```

---

Note that you can reduce your alphabet, using just a string, you can accessing exactly the same as a tuple or a list

```
ALPH = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 .,?!'

def cypher(text, num):
    ''' Encypts provided message with given cyphering number'''
    coded = ''
    for char in text.upper():
        letter_i = ALPH.index(char)
        coded_letter = ALPH[(letter_i + num) % len(ALPH)]
        coded += coded_letter
    print(f'Your encrypted phrase is: {coded}')
```

Comment: Ok, so it works perfectly as expected. However would you be kind enough to explain why does it work like that?

I know how modulo works itself... on numbers. But I have absolutely no idea, why it works this way here :/

Comment: @KacperDzida Explain the modulo operator ? I've add a small example

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (the remainder operator):

```py
coded_letter = alph[(letter_i + num) % len(alph)]
```

In python, this will also work for negatives (`-1 % 10 == 9`), so you can have `alpha[(letter_i - num) % len(alph)]` as well for `decypher`.